# functions not getting hoisted inside if block

Tags: javascript

```js
f1(); 
    
if (true) {
   function f1() { console.log( "a" ); }
} else {
   function f1() { console.log( "b" ); }
}
```

From the concept of function hoisting, this should always show "b" but instead it is showing "a". Does an if statement block scopes the function? But ES5 does not have block scopes.

Comment: `if (true) ` is always true.

Comment: FWIW, it logs `b`…

Comment: I'm just getting `Uncaught TypeError: f1 is not a function` (I'm using Chrome)

Comment: @linga Regardless, if that made any difference, it should throw a "function not defined" error when you try to call `f1` before defining it.

Comment: …whiiiiiich apparently it does, for some at least (great timing @4castle). Seems to be a browser inconsistency then.

Comment: @deceze Hmm.. that's how javascript works?

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet Well, in OS X Safari, the second function is apparently getting hoisted as expected.

Comment: FireFox had this "block scope" for functions declared in an `if` block, I thought they've stopped to support it, but looks like they haven't.

Comment: @deceze I agree, you are right

Comment: Interesting...I'm using Browser Stack to test the snippets: IE 10 = `b`, IE 11 = `Error: Object Expected`, Firefox _latest_ = `TypeError: f1 is not defined`, Chrome _latest_ = `Uncaught TypeError: f1 is not a function`, Opera _latest_ = `Uncaught TypeError: f1 is not a function`, Safari _OS X 10.1_ = `b`. @deceze Good call on the browser inconsistencies...

Comment: [The MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Differences) says: "_A function declaration is ... turned into a function expression [when it] is no longer a "source element" of a function or the script itself_" Afaik this is not a standard behavior, or was this included to standard in ES2015 ..?

Comment: @War10ck Which is even more interesting because the OP said theirs always spits out "a"...

Comment: @deceze As interesting as this question is, is it on topic? There doesn't seem to be a clear problem statement, the behavior the OP mentions is not replicable, and has "Why doesn't this code work?" undertones.

Comment: @mhodges It points to an inconsistency across browsers (although that's only apparent from the comments and should be edited into the question), which I think is perfectly on topic, no?

Comment: @deceze The question as it stands now should be put on hold as off-topic until it is edited to include specific questions about the browser inconsistencies. And the question should be geared toward asking how to work around the inconsistencies, not just "why doesn't this code work across browsers?", right?